# Bootstrap Modal with Dynamic MySQL Data using Ajax & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, stored-procedures

I am trying to use this tutorial [Here](http://www.codingcage.com/2016/09/bootstrap-modal-with-dynamic-mysql-data.html) about using bootstrap modal to show dynamic MySQL Data using Ajax & PHP, the only difference is that I am using Stored Procedures to pull the data from MySQL.

I am using

**My index:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">      
    <ul class="contact_list">
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['Search'])) {
            $r = DB::Call("[spEmployeeSelectAll]", array("EmployeeCode" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "FullName" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "DepartmentID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT, "ProjectID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT), array($_POST['EmployeeCode'], $_POST['FullName'], $_POST['DepartmentID'], $_POST['ProjectID']));
            foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
                echo '  
                        <li class="contact_item" >
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLarge" data-id="' . $value['EmployeeCode'] . '" id="getUser">
                                <span class="contact_content">
                                    <h2>' . $value['FullName'] . '</h2>
                                    <span class="text-muted">' . $value['Designation'] . '</span>
                                    <small class="text-muted">' . $value['Department'] . '</small>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                     ';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="view-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
     <div class="modal-content">  

        <div class="modal-header"> 
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button> 
           <h4 class="modal-title">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> User Profile
           </h4> 
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-body">                     
           <div id="modal-loader" style="display: none; text-align: center;">
           <!-- ajax loader -->
           <img src="ajax-loader.gif">
           </div>

           <!-- mysql data will be load here -->                          
           <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-footer"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
        </div> 

    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Function:**

```
(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '#getUser', function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

 var uid = $(this).data('EmployeeCode'); // get id of clicked row

 $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // leave this div blank
 $('#modal-loader').show();      // load ajax loader on button click

 $.ajax({
      url: 'getuser.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'id='+uid,
      dataType: 'html'
 })
 .done(function(data){
      console.log(data); 
      $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // blank before load.
      $('#dynamic-content').html(data); // load here
      $('#modal-loader').hide(); // hide loader  
 })
 .fail(function(){
      $('#dynamic-content').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> Something went wrong, Please try again...');
      $('#modal-loader').hide();
 });

});
});
```

**getuser.php**

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    $r = DB::Call("[spEmployeeSelectAll]", array("EmployeeCode" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "FullName" => \PDO::PARAM_STR, "DepartmentID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT, "ProjectID" => \PDO::PARAM_INT), array($_POST['EmployeeCode'], $_POST['FullName'], $_POST['DepartmentID'], $_POST['ProjectID']));
    if (isset($_REQUEST['EmployeeCode'])) {

        ?>

        <div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <td><?php echo $value['FullName']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
        </table>

        </div>

        <?php               
    }

    ?>
```

My Stored Procedures Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployeeSelectAll]
    @EmployeeCode   AS NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @FullName       AS NVARCHAR(250)= '',
    @DepartmentID   AS NVARCHAR(250) = 0,
    @ProjectID      AS VARCHAR(250) = 0

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT      Employee.EmployeeID,
                Employee.EmployeeCode,
                Employee.FullName,
                Department.Department,
                Designation.Designation,
                Project.Project

    FROM        tbEmployee Employee
    INNER JOIN  tbDesignation Designation ON Employee.DesignationID = Designation.DesignationID
    INNER JOIN  tbDepartment Department ON Employee.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN  tbProject Project ON Employee.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID

    WHERE       Employee.IsDeleted      = 0

    AND         Employee.EmployeeCode   LIKE '%' + @EmployeeCode + '%'
    AND         Employee.FullName       LIKE '%' + @FullName + '%'

    AND         Employee.DepartmentID   = CASE WHEN @DepartmentID > 0 THEN @DepartmentID ELSE Employee.DepartmentID END
    AND         Employee.ProjectID  = CASE WHEN @ProjectID > 0 THEN @ProjectID ELSE Employee.ProjectID END

END
```

My issue is when every I click on the link for the modal to show up .. nothing show up and the console show me this warning:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Any ideas about how to solve this issue?